# Doctrine password hash after regexp validate

Tags: php, doctrine, validation

I have a problem during save password on database. I have password field with complex regexp validator (minlenght + special chars + alphanumerics). After send form, password value is checked by validator. After that (if value is valid) I would like hash password and finally save this value, but regexp validator still validate field and return error.

How can i disable validator before finally save hashed value?

Sorry for my english!

Code:

**On user model:**

```
 public function setTableDefinition()
 {
     $this->hasColumn('password', 'string', 32, array ('notnull'=>true, 'minlength'=>8, 'regexp'=> '/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$/'));
     .......
 }

 public function setUp()
 {
        $this->addListener(new userChangeListener());
 }
```

**On listener:**

```
class userChangeListener extends Doctrine_Record_Listener
{
    public function postValidate(Doctrine_Event $event)
    {
        $invoker = $event->getInvoker();
        $invoker->password = md5($invoker->password);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Maybe post some code. You just need to make sure that you do the validation before the hash. So, it will validate, and then after validation you can hash it and store it.

Comment: Exactly, I know that is postValidate listener, but not working at all

Comment: problem solved - i changed public function postValidate(Doctrine_Event $event) -> public function postValidate($event) and it works!